# Nonnegativity of solution of $u_t=\Delta u+u$

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

Consider the following evolution equation

$$u_t=\Delta u+u$$
in a bounded and regular open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$, with smooth initial conditions $u_0\geq 0$ and homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.

It is known that this equation has a smooth global solution $u$. **My goal** is to prove that the solution remains nonnegative. So I consider $w=\min(0,u)$ and its energy $E(t):=\int_\Omega w^2 dx$. We know that 
\begin{align}
E(0) &= \int_\Omega w(0,x)^2 dx \\
&=\int_\Omega \min(0,u(0,x))^2 dx \\
&=\int_\Omega \min(0,u_0(x))^2 dx \\
&=0
\end{align}

By differentiating  $E(t)$ and using integration parts we get

\begin{align}
E'(t) &= 2\int_\Omega ww_t \\
&= 2\int_\Omega wu_t \\
&= 2\int_\Omega w\Delta u+2\int_\Omega wu \\
&= -2\int_\Omega \nabla w \cdot \nabla u+2\int_\Omega w^2 \\
&= -2\int_\Omega |\nabla w|^2+2E(t) \\
&\leq-\frac{2}{c^2}\int_\Omega w^2 dx+2E(t)\\
&\leq\left(2-\frac{2}{c^2}\right)E(t),\quad \text{for almost every} \ t
\end{align}
where $c$ is the Poincaré constant. 
Thus $E(t)\leq e^{\left(2-\frac{2}{c^2}\right)t}E(0)=0$ for almost every $t$
which implies that for a.e $t\geq 0$ $w(t,x)=0$ for a.e $x\in \Omega$. But since $w=\min(0,u)$ is continuous then $w(t,x)=0$ for all  $t\geq 0$ and for all $x\in \Omega.$ Therefore $u(t,x)\geq 0$  for all  $t\geq 0$ and for all $x\in \Omega.$

**My concerns are**:

**1)** How can I justify the derivation under integral sign $E'(t)=2\int_\Omega ww_t$ because unlike $u$ which is smooth, $w=\min(0,u)$ has only weak time derivative $w_t=u_t \mathbb{1}_{\{u\leq0\}}.$

**2)** In the end I proved that for a.e $t\geq 0$, $\int w(t,x)^2dx=0$, thus for a.e $t\geq 0$: $w(t,x)=0$ for a.e $x\in \Omega$. I then concluded by continuity of $w$ that this holds for all  $t\geq 0$ and for all $x\in \Omega.$  I am not use but the space negligable sets of $\Omega$ might depend on time $t$. Does this make my argument still valid?

Comment: Can't we apply a comparison principle to show non negativity of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to write your procedure rigurously in the following way. First of all notice that we can re-write $w(t,x)$ as $$
w(t,x)=\dfrac{u-\vert u\vert}{2}.
$$
Thus, differentiating we have $$
w_t=\dfrac{1}{2}\big(u_t-\hbox{sgn}(u)u_t\big)=\dfrac{1}{2}(1-\hbox{sgn}(u))u_t.
$$
Now, replacing this in $E'(t)$ we obtain $$
E'(t)=2\int w w_t=\int (\Delta u+u)(1-\hbox{sgn}(u))w
$$
Finally, integrating  by parts we obtain $$
E'(t)=-\int (1-\hbox{sgn}(u))\nabla u\cdot\nabla w+\int (1-\hbox{sgn}(u))uw, 
$$
where the Dirac's delta dissapears because it is multiply by $w$, which is zero on the set $\{u=0\}$. Finally, noticing that $$
(1-\hbox{sgn}(u))u=2w \quad \hbox{and} \quad (1-\hbox{sgn}(u))\nabla u=2\nabla w,
$$
you obtain the result proceeding exactly as you did on your question.

Comment: Hi, you still used the same derivation under integral sign $E'(t)=2\int w w_t$ using weak derivatives. How can we justify that?

Comment: There is no problem there, as the proof shows. The important part is that you are inside the integral and that $w$ has a weak-derivative.

Comment: But it's a time weak derivative inside a space integral...